# 'T' & 'F' reads as True and False from database

Tags: r, rodbc

I need to read from a data base where one of the columns contains 'T' and 'F' values using RODBC sqlQuery function.  However my results keep coming out with 'TRUE' and 'FALSE'.  I found the following post for reading csv files.  Is there a similar workaround for the sqlQuery function?

[read.table reads "T" as TRUE and "F" as FALSE, how to avoid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214471/read-table-reads-t-as-true-and-f-as-false-in-r-how-to-avoid)

Edit : This is the code I'm running as requested in the comments.  It won't be executable without access to the DB though ...

```
conn = odbcConnect(dataBaseName)
results = sqlQuery(conn, paste0("select ID, andate, antime from table.e4 where ticker in (",paste(shQuote(IDvector, type = "sh"), collapse = ', '),");"))
close(conn)
```

ID is the field that contains 'T's and 'Fs

Comment: Post a toy example for people to work with if you can. It always helps.

Comment: I tend to go through the `DBI` package and this gets the correct types from my database.  Not sure how much code you have, but you could try it as a test.  As @SimonO101 said, some example code would help.

Comment: Have you looked at the `as.is` option for `sqlQuery`?

Comment: It worked!  Thanks so much.  If you post it as an answer I'll be more than happy to accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sqlQuery` function has `as.is` option, from [the RODBC manual](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RODBC/RODBC.pdf):

> **as.is** which (if any) columns returned as character should be converted to another type? Allowed values are as for read.table. See
>   ‘Details’.
>
> **Details**
>   ... if `as.is` is true for a column, it is returned as a character
>   vector. Otherwise (where detected) date, datetime and timestamp values
>   are converted to the "Date" or "POSIXct" class. ...