# read.table unexpectedly interprets "T" as TRUE

Tags: r

I have found an issue where R seems to interpret `"T"` as `TRUE` even while using all means to avoid doing so (at least according to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16214471/read-table-reads-t-as-true-and-f-as-false-in-r-how-to-avoid)).

Example data (saved as "test.txt"):

```
col1    col2
1   T
2   T
3   T
4   T
5   T
6   T
7   T
8   T
9   T
```

Example code:

```
read.table("test.txt", as.is=TRUE, header=TRUE, 
   stringsAsFactors=FALSE, colClasses=c(character()))
```

Produces:

```
  col1 col2
1    1 TRUE
2    2 TRUE
3    3 TRUE
4    4 TRUE
5    5 TRUE
6    6 TRUE
7    7 TRUE
8    8 TRUE
9    9 TRUE
```

Only non-ideal solution I found was to set header=FALSE:

```
read.table("test.txt", as.is=TRUE, header=FALSE, 
    stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
    colClasses=c(character()))        


     V1   V2
1  col1 col2
2     1    T
3     2    T
4     3    T
5     4    T
6     5    T
7     6    T
8     7    T
9     8    T
10    9    T
```

I realize this may seem somewhat contrived, but this edge case is genuine in that a human gene is named actually `"T"` (!) with values in `col1` being positions within that gene.

Thanks in advance for the help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What makes you think this is "unexpectedly" ?

R guesses for you (and that is generally helpful), but if you know better, use the `colClasses=...` argument to tell R.

```
R> res <- read.table(textConnection("col1 col2\n1 T\n2 T\n3 T"), 
+                    header=TRUE, colClasses=c("numeric", "character"))
R> res
    col1 col2
 1    1    T 
 2    2    T 
 3    3    T 
R> sapply(res, class)
        col1        col2  
   "numeric" "character"  
R>
```

Your post was a little oddly formatted so I didn't see at first that you did in fact specify `colClasses`.  Despite the recycling rule I always recommend to supply a vector
with as many entries as you have columns.

Comment: @Vince: Note that Dirk is using `"character"` instead of `character()`; if you make that change in your code yours also works, though now both columns are character class.

Comment: @Dirk: Thanks. I assumed (falsely) unexpected because setting header=FALSE seems to fix the issue, and the lack of error by my erroneous use of character() instead of "character" for colClasses confused me. But yes, you are correct, under most circumstances this behavior should be expected. I just assumed my use of colClasses should have fixed it.

Comment: @Aaron: thanks! Should R report an error when given a non-character vector for value of colClasses?

Comment: Well, perhaps, but that wouldn't have solved this issue because `character()` creates an empty character vector.  So it was a character vector, it just had no entries.